Find curve minimizing energy loss due to friction
I am looking for an ansatz of the following problem:
Given a mass $m$ moving in a constant gravitational field along curves $C$ connecting two fixed points I want to find the curve $C_0$ that minimizes the total energy loss
$$ \Delta E[C] = m \mu \int_C ds \left| \mathbf{a}_n \right| $$
due to friction.
$\mu$ is the friction coefficient, and $\mathbf{a}_n$ is the normal acceleration, defined as the projection of the total acceleration on the normal vector of $C$
$$ \mathbf{a}_n = v^{-1} (\ddot{\mathbf{r}} + g \mathbf{e}_z, \Omega \dot{\mathbf{r}}) $$
$\Omega$ implements a 90° rotation from the tangent direction $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ to the normal direction (I think this is the simplest way to express that, avoiding a second derivative).
This is related to the curvature $\kappa$ via $a_n = \kappa v^2$.
Of course, the motion must also satisfy the usual e.o.m.
$$ m \ddot{\mathbf{r}} + mg \mathbf{e}_z + m \mu v^{-1} \left| \mathbf{a}_n \right| \dot{\mathbf{r}} = 0 $$
with friction force in tangent direction.
The constraint of motion along a curve $C$ could be fixed directly using cartesian coordinates $\mathbf{r} = (x, c_y(x))$, polar coordinates
$\mathbf{r} = c_r(\phi) \hat{\mathbb{e}}(\phi)$ ... or it could be implemented using as Langrangian multiplier $\lambda$ with a constraint $C(\mathbb{r})$, resulting in constraint forces $\lambda \mathbf{\nabla} C(\mathbb{r})$ plus the condition $C(\mathbb{r}) = 0$.
Playing around with the latter option, and projecting the e.o.m. to the tangent and to the normal direction, respectively, one finds two equations
$$ \dot{E} + m \mu (\ddot{\mathbf{r}} + g e_z, \Omega \dot{\mathbf{r}}) = 0 $$
$$ m (\ddot{\mathbf{r}} + g \hat{\mathbf{e}}_z, \Omega \dot{\mathbf{r}}) + m \lambda (\mathbf{\nabla} C, \Omega \dot{\mathbf{r}}) = 0 $$
where
$$ E = \frac{m}{2} \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 + mgz $$
and where I used
$$ (\mathbf{\nabla}C, \dot{\mathbf{r}}) = 0 $$
The first (tangent) e.o.m. is just the energy loss due to friction, whereas the second one (normal) allows one to express the energy loss in terms of the geometry of the curve only.
The velocity is perpendicular to the constrain forces, so the rotated velocity is normal, therefore the two terms in the scalar product parallel, i.e.
$$ (\mathbf{\nabla} C, \Omega \dot{\mathbf{r}}) \sim | \mathbf{\nabla} C | v $$
(modulo a sign)
Plugging this into the first equation yields
$$ \Delta E[C] = m \mu \int_C ds \left| \mathbf{a}_n \right| = - m \mu \int_0^T dt (\ddot{\mathbf{r}} + g e_z, \Omega \dot{\mathbf{r}}) \sim \int_C ds \lambda | \mathbf{\nabla} C | $$
Problem enter stage
Calculating the brachistochrone (minimizing time instead of energy loss), one uses similar ideas, but in addition one uses energy conservation, i.e.
$$ v^2(y) = \frac{2}{m}E_0 - 2gy $$
Here, this looks terrible, simply b/c
$$ v^2(t) = \frac{2}{m}E(t) - 2gy(t) = \frac{2}{m}\left( E_0 - \int_0^t dt^\prime \dot{E}(t^\prime) \right) - 2gy(t)  $$
which depends on the entire history of the motion along the unknown curve $C$.
Question
Is there any reasonable way to proceed?
